# Eclipse Oxygen: 'Download additional server adapters' link missing

Tags: eclipse, glassfish, eclipse-oxygen

I have Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers, version: Oxygen Release (4.7.0) and 'Download additional server adapters' link missing from 'Define a New Server' wizard. I'd like to use Glassfish, but it's not in the server type list. 
How can I add a ServerType to eclipse?

Comment: So your question is `How can I add a ServerType to eclipse?` ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, the question was missing :D

Comment: So what to do to make  "Download additional server adapters" link visible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on `Help` -> `Eclipse Marketplace`

Search for "glassfish" and install the "Glassfish Tools", restart Eclipse and then you can add your Glassfish server.

More details/alternative solution:

[How to add glassfish tools to eclipse oxygen 3a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50912824/how-to-add-glassfish-tools-to-eclipse-oxygen-3a)

Comment: Glassfish Tools only supports older versions of GlassFish 4 and 3.  Not 5 which is the current release.  There should be a way to manually add GlassFish 5 but I do not yet know how to do it.

Comment: This also worked for adding JBoss AS server types, thanks.

Comment: I get "The following solutions are not available: GlassFish Tools". Any help ?

Comment: I updated the answer with a link to a more detailed solution.